# Sorting a list following specific order of elements

Tags: python, list, sorting, count

Let's say that I need to sort a list like:

`A=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]`

following a ratio between 1 and 0 of 4:1, obtaining so `A=[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]`.

Is that possible?
I tried to use a `count` comand in this way:

```
scheme=[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
       
for k, number in enumerate(scheme):
    visited.append(number)
    scheme[k] += visited.count(number)/len(scheme)

for z in scheme:
    new = sorted(scheme).index(z)
    final.append(sorted(que)[new])
```

But this is not a comfortable approach since `scheme`, the guide list, depends strongly on initial list A lenght.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the list only contain ones and zeroes? And to clarify, the ordering should be 4:1 runs of ones and zeros, followed by the remaining ones, followed by the remaining zeroes -- is this correct?

Comment: How does your sample output satisfy the ratio requirement?

Comment: Could you please explain the logic of the scheme? For instance, using [`more_itertools.interleave_evenly`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.interleave_evenly) on `A` returns `[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]`

Comment: This seems like a synthetic exercise - what exactly are the constraints either in practice or as given? Are the elements always value-like, i.e. they are indistinguishable when equal? Is the list always pre-sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using simple arithmetic

Assuming the sequence contains only zeroes and ones.

```py
from collections import Counter

def reorder_4_1(seq):
    c = Counter(seq)
    q1, r1 = divmod(c[1], 4)
    diff = q1 - c[0]
    if diff > 0:
        return [1,1,1,1,0] * c[0] + [1] * (diff + r1)
    else:
        return [1,1,1,1,0] * q1 + [1] * r1 + [0] * (-diff)

print( reorder_4_1([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]) )
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

### Using module `itertools`

Using recipe `roundrobin` from [the `itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

#### Assuming there are two groups of elements to interleave 4:1

```py
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))

def interleave_4_1(a, b):
    a = iter(a)
    b = iter(b)
    return roundrobin(a, a, a, a, b)

print(list( interleave_4_1([1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0]) ))
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

#### Assuming the sequence is guaranteed to be a list of ones and zeroes

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import repeat

# def roundrobin...

def reorder_4_1(seq):
    c = Counter(seq)
    a = repeat(1, c[1])
    b = repeat(0, c[0])
    return roundrobin(a, a, a, a, b)

print(list( reorder_4_1([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]) ))
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed (the arithmetic solution in particular), thank you a lot!
How would it be if I had a 2D list where each 1 and 0 in the original list is coupled with a str? 
For example: [(0, 'Rome'), (1, 'London'), (1, 'New York'),...]

I'm curious about the last IF section, especially the RETURN of the final list with ones and zeros coupled properly with their name, in this different case. Sorry for bothering again!

Comment: @AndreaCichellero You can group the cities in two lists by doing `data = [(0, 'Rome'), (1, 'London'), (1, 'New York'),...]; zeroes = [city for num, city in data if num == 0]; ones = [city for num, city in data if num == 1` then use `list(interleave_4_1(ones, zeroes))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way without collections or itertools, assuming only zeroes and ones and that you want ones first and then zeroes after:

```
def ratio_sort(x,y,lst):

    counter_dict = {1:0,0:0}
    for num in lst:   # count the amount of ones and zeroes in lst
        counter_dict[num]+=1
    
    # find how many groups of ones and zeroes we have
    one_groups = counter_dict[1]//x 
    zero_groups = counter_dict[0]//y

    new_list = []
    for i in range(min(one_groups, zero_groups)):  # add ratios of ones and zeroes to new list
        new_list.extend(([1]*x)+([0]*y))
        counter_dict[1]-=x
        counter_dict[0]-=y

    new_list.extend(([1]*counter_dict[1])+([0]*counter_dict[0]))  # insert the leftovers
    return new_list
```

Comment: Your big loop `for i in range(min(one_groups, zero_groups)):` could simply be replaced by `new_list = ([1] * x + [0] * y) * min(one_groups, zero_groups)`

Comment: @Stef So if I would do that I would need to also subtract from each dictionary entry by `x*min(one_groups, zero_groups)` and `y*min(one_groups, zero_groups)`, and yes it works great that way too, thanks!